# Как для запроса Subscribe установить Filter-TopicExpression?

Tags: python, onvif

использую quatanium/python-onvif для выполнения запросов.

Как для запроса Subscribe я могу установить Filter-TopicExpression?

Для 'ConsumerReference' и 'InitialTerminationTime' я делаю след. образом:

```
subscribe.create_type('Subscribe')       
subscribe.Subscribe({'ConsumerReference': "http://10.1.50.11:8000",
                     'InitialTerminationTime': 'PT60S'
                   })
```

Ну вот ждя фильтра не понятно как сделать. Можете помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found is a great solution:

```
    topic_expression_type = zeep_client.get_type('TopicExpressionType')
    from zeep import xsd
    topic_exp = xsd.Element('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2}TopicExpression',xsd.ComplexType(topic_expression_type))
    subscribe = notification.create_type('Subscribe')
    any = xsd.AnyObject(topic_exp,topic_expression_type(_value_1=xsd.AnyObject(xsd.String(), 'o2kvmd:Telemetry//.'),Dialect='http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tev/topicExpression/ConcreteSet'))
    obj = subscribe(ConsumerReference='http://10.1.50.11:8000', InitialTerminationTime='PT60S', Filter={'_value_1': any})
    notification.Subscribe(obj)
```